# How to make sure that installed Windows 7 OS is genuine, when buying used laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, license, windows-genuine-advantage

Soon I am going to buy a used laptop computer. I am checking advertisements, and some of the sellers promise a genuine copy of Windows 7 OS installed on the system.

On a couple of occasions I have already seen Windows genuine tests showing that the installed OS has a valid license. Later however, it proved to be a cracked copy.

**When trying out the potential new computer, how to make sure that the installed Windows 7  actually is genuine, and not a cracked version ?**

Comment: Purchase for an a Microsoft OEM

Comment: Surely if the Laptop was sold new with an OEM copy of Windows, and the license is affixed to the laptop, it must be a legitimate copy of Windows.  (OEM licenses are bound to the system they were supplied with and according to the license can't be transferred - thus if the OEM sold it with Windows 7 surely it must still have a license for that Windows 7)

Comment: Windows 8.x does things better.  If you purchase a laptop that "comes" with a Windows 8 licence, that licence is actually encrypted in the laptop's BIOS.  You can wipe the hard drive clean and use an OEM Windows 8.x install DVD to re-install the OS. Windows will pick up the key in the BIOS without ever asking you. Too easy. You can always google laptop specifications to check if a particular model comes with a Windows 8.x license. http://www.cnet.com/news/windows-8-moves-to-bios-based-product-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/exe-validation.aspx

Download the genuine validation tool. Even if they have messed with the validator that is part of Windows this should still pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the Genuine Validation Tool, it will tell you if the PRODUCT KEY is genuine, or is being a cracked version. However it **will not check** Whether windows 7 was installed using some tampered ISO !

I suggest you try use the [Magical Jelley Bean Key Finder](https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/), it will fetch you the product key ( that was used on installation ) from the registry if it is legit.

Also if you will do a clean install yourslef, download the genuine official [Windows ISO](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links) . That's just my paranoid self though :x

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 – Activate Windows Dialog**

The first way to validate that Windows 7 is genuine is to click on Start, then type in activate windows in the search box.
[image]
If your copy of Windows 7 is activated and genuine, you will ge t a message that says “**Activation was successful**” and you will see the Microsoft Genuine software logo on the right hand side

[image]

**Method 2 – Control Panel**

The third way to check for genuine Windows 7 is to go to the Control Panel. Click on Start, then Control Panel, then click on System and Security, and finally click on System.
[image]
Then scroll all the way down to the bottom and you should see a section called Windows activation, which says **“Windows is activated”** and gives you the Product ID. It also includes the genuine Microsoft software logo.
[image]

[Courtesy](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/check-if-windows-7-is-genuine/)

Method 3 : open cmd.exe and type:

```
slmgr.vbs /dli
```

you can see licenced status as follows:
[image]